# Blocking F5 refresh not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript

Here is the code that worked earlier, but now doesn't work anymore. Does anyone know why?

```
document.onkeydown = function()
 {
      if(event.keyCode==116) {
          event.keyCode=0;
          event.returnValue = false;
      }
}

// To avoid refresh, using context menu of the browser
document.oncontextmenu = function() {event.returnValue = false;}
```

Comment: Pass `event` parameter to event handler. i.e. `document.oncontextmenu = function(event) {event.returnValue = false;}`

Comment: ya i passed onkeydown="return (event.keyCode == 116)"  but doesn't work.

Comment: `document.onkeydown = function(event)`

Comment: sorry not working

Comment: Code is correct. You might have some other javascript error which prevents this code execution. Check on console if there any error.

Comment: @Praveen please check my code as well . Thanks :)

Comment: Small note, the reason why your code "sometimes" seems to work is because some browsers - particularly ones with backwards compatibility with old IE - maintain the `window.event` global variable to match whatever event is going on, meaning `event.returnValue` will seem to work even though it's archaic.

Comment: It is not recommended to prevent a user to refresh the page via F5. Mostly because it is pointless (can be refreshed manually, via right click or console)

Answer (score 1):

You refer to `event` in your functions, but you never actually pass it:

```
document.onkeydown = function(){ /* ... */ }
document.oncontextmenu = function() {event.returnValue = false; }

// should be
document.onkeydown = function(event){ /* ... */ }
document.oncontextmenu = function(event) {event.returnValue = false; }
```

In the first version of the oncontextmenu you set 'returnvalue' of object 'event' to false, but it doesnt exist because you never actually pass it on to the function.

Answer (score 0):

Recieve the event in your function

```
document.onkeydown = function(event)
 {
          if(event.keyCode==116) {
          event.keyCode=0;
          event.returnValue = false;
          }
}
```

Or Try preventing the action by that key

```
document.onkeydown = function(event)
 {
          if(event.keyCode==116) {
          event.preventDefault();          
          }
}
```

Comment: Please don't just post code. You should explain what you've changed, why you changed it, and why it fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 <script>
 window.onload = function () {
    document.onkeydown = function (e) {
        return (e.which || e.keyCode) != 116;
    };
 }
</script>
```